# Cannot use "using" declaration for std::tuple on Apple LLVM 7.3.0

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, using-declaration

I'm attempting to use `tuple` in my program, and for some reason I am not able to simplify the call with a `using` declaration. For example:

```
#include <tuple>

using std::tuple;

...
```

This throws an error when attempting to compile it:

```
error: no member named 'tuple' in namespace 'std'
```

I'm able to use `using` declarations for other things (like `std::string`, `std::get`, etc.) just fine. I think I've narrowed it down to a compiler issue, but I don't have control over which compiler I get to use (university server) and I can't find anything online showing a lack of support for this header or anything. Here is my compiler information:

```
$ clang++ -v

Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Any thoughts? Here's an example of it working elsewhere: http://cpp.sh/5bofm

Comment: Are you compiling with standard version set to before C++11?

Comment: @eukaryota I'm compiling with default flags except for warnings, so I'm not sure whether that's the case or not

Comment: So you can use `std::tuple` in your code, it's just the `using` part that's not working... ?

Comment: @super I just commented out `using std::tuple;` and made all of the places I was calling it include the namespace, and it still does not work. This makes me think that `<tuple>` is not included in this version of LLVM

Comment: @IsaacCorbrey Try specifying `-std=c++11` on the compiler command line and use the exact code you posted as test (with the three dots removed). Does it still give an error?

Comment: @eukaryota That fixed it, thank you! If you wanna put that as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the include did not give a preprocessor error, it is likely that the tuple header does exist and that this is not a case of a messed-up/out-of-date C++ standard library install.

However `tuple` not being defined in `std` is expected for all the C++ standards before C++11.

With a standard installation and without additional flags your Clang's version should be using C++14, however this seems to have been modified by whoever is maintaining that system or some package maintainer.

To make sure you are using the most recent C++ language standard add `-std=c++17` to the compiler invocation or at least `-std=c++14` if C++17 is too recent for some reason, e.g. compatibility with older compiler installations. In particular if your are coding for a university class, you might want to ask to clarify up to which C++ standard is acceptable to use.

Comment: if you are using cmake:
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)